# DotNetOpenAuth and ResourceServer service https configuration

Tags: wcf, ssl, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to configure the DataApi.svc service of the DotNetOpenAuth to call my resources via https using AJAX.

I can call the service and hit the code behind but the OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext will be not authenticated

In IIS, I have "Anonymous authentication" set to "true".

In Fiddler I can see that the header is sent:
Authorization: Bearer gAAAAMcRmG5vw3LykShq7cNOEGUACBiNtlVGxGYdSVfkkXjR-[truncated]

The interface is decorated like that:

> [ServiceContract]
>   public interface IDataApi {
>
> > [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/email", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
> >     string GetEmail();

And here is my config:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DataApiBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DataApiWebBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DataApiBehavior" name="OAuthResourceServer.DataApi">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="OAuthResourceServer.Code.IDataApi" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="OAuthResourceServer.Code.IDataApi" behaviorConfiguration="DataApiWebBehavior">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

Any idea of what can be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the

```
 <serviceAuthorizationserviceAuthorizationManagerType="OAuthResourceServer.Code.OAuthAuthorizationManager, OAuthResourceServer" principalPermissionMode="Custom" />
```

in the service behavior! Solved :)